# Referencing overlapping arrays through pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, overlap

I need to perform a `memmove()`-style operation with pointers that are tuned to overlapping arrays. More precisely, I need to copy `b(:)` into `a(:)`.

[image: Pointers aliasing illustration]

In C programming language I would have called `memmove(a, b, N)`. But, as far as I know, Fortran Standard is very strict when it comes to pointer aliasing.

So, which of the following three options is safe to use (according to the Standard), and which would result in undefined behaviour:

- vector syntax with aliased pointers (Option 1),
- explicit do-loop with aliased pointers (Option 2),
- call to a routine that takes overlapping arrays as arguments (Option 3)

?

```
program ptr
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ARRAY_SIZE = 10, N = 6
  integer, target :: array(ARRAY_SIZE)
  integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a, b
  integer :: i

  a => array(1: N)
  b => array(3: N+2)

  ! Option 1
  a(1: N) = b(1: N)

  ! Option 2
  do i = 1, N
    a(i) = b(i)
  end do

  ! Option 3
  call foobar(a, b, N)

  contains

    subroutine foobar(a, b, length)
      integer, dimension(:), intent(out) :: a
      integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: b
      integer, intent(in) :: length

      a(1: length) = b(1: length)
    end subroutine foobar
end program ptr
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, yes, correct. I want to move elements of the arrays: a(1)=b(1), a(2)=b(2), ... a(6)=b(6). Of course, the order of assignments is important; they should be performed one by one as specified.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fortran-array-data-and-arguments-and-vectorization The end of this page says that when overlap exists between RHS and LHS, an array temporary will be created, but I'm not sure whether this is common for all compilers...

Comment: Yes, that is common for all compilers. The problem is the compiler will not assume any overlap in the subroutine in the question.

Comment: To be clear, some compiler can optimize the temporary and use a loop similar to Option 2. All compilers should get the result right according to the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 are OK, the compiler knows that pointers can alias.

The subroutine is OK per se, but you cannot pass there two aliased arguments, that is indeed against the standard (undefined behaviour is a C term). You can make the arguments `pointer`, then aliasing is possible and the program will be standard conforming.

```
  integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a
  integer, dimension(:), pointer :: b
```

I also deleted the intents, because they relate to the pointer association status, not to the target value, as IanH commented. Also, Fortran2003 is required for them.